# Sourcetree listing unmodified files as modified for Bitbucket repository

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I just reinstalled my OS and copied my repositories back to disk. 2 Bitbucket, and 1 Github. Then, I installed SourceTree and added both accounts(Github and Bitbucket). Finally, I used the "Add Existing Local Repository" function of SourceTree to add all three repositories.

Now, while everything seems fine with my Github repository, SourceTree is listing every single file in both Bitbucket repositories as modified, even though most of them have not been modified. Selecting any of the supposedly modified files in SourceTree's "File Status" section shows an empty box in the diff on the right.

What's going on here?

Edit: DiffMerge confirms the files that SourceTree things are modified, are identical to the remote.

Comment: Did you check permissions of the files? Git manages file permissions, too.

Comment: Recently figured this may be it. Manual diff at terminal gives info like "old mode 100644 \n new mode 100755" - really not sure how simply copy/pasting files could have done this =/

Comment: [umask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) or something?

Comment: very strange: github thinks permissions for all the files is 755, but the C++ function stat() shows the permissions are 777. Maybe git is wrong about the files needing to be 644 too? who knows. I'm looking at my untainted backup, and 'filemode=true' in the git config file(meaning that's what it was before reinstall). Still have no idea how all the permissions got changed, but setting "filemode = false" seems to have fixed things...

Comment: My external drive is formatted as ExFAT as opposed to whatever macs use, so maybe that's it - http://superuser.com/questions/468291/chmoding-file-on-exfat#answer-468293

Comment: @bitwise, Git does track permissions but not with the same granularity as your filesystem. It sees files as executable (755) or not (644), and that's it.

Comment: @Chris With this in mind, I figured (666) probably made sense. After running `find . -type f -exec chmod 666 {} +` on my repo, I was able to set 'filemode' back to 'true' with expected results. Adding to my confusion yesterday was that my first attempt was `chmod -R 666 .`, which made all the folders un-traversable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had copied my repo to/from a drive that didn't support unix style permissions(ExFat). So after the round-trip, the permissions had been reset to default(777), which was detected by git as a difference.

777 includes execute permissions, which was not originally present for my files(they were 666 - read/write).

The solution was to run the following command on my repository, which removed the extra execute permissions from all files:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 666 {} +
```

The above command targets files only, because execute permissions are required for folders to be traversable.